# Solve $x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve $x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}$

$\Rightarrow (x+2)^2=(\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}})^2 \tag{1}$

$\Rightarrow x^2+4x+4=4+x\sqrt{8-x} \tag{2}$

$\Rightarrow x^2+4x=x\sqrt{8-x} \tag{3}$

$\Rightarrow (x^2+4x)^2=(x\sqrt{8-x})^2 \tag{4}$

$\Rightarrow x^4+8x^3+16x^2=8x^2-x^3 \tag{5}$

$\Rightarrow x^4+9x^3+8x^2=0 \tag{6}$

$\Rightarrow x^2+9x+8=0 \tag{7}$

$\Rightarrow (x+8)(x+1)=0 \tag{8}$

Therefore $x=-8, -1$.

The answer is given as $x=-8,-1,0$. My problem is since there are square roots involved, normally I only take the positive $x$ (and there are no negative signs before the square roots). In this case, $x=-8$ and $x=-1$ are both negative, yet the solution $x=-1$ works in the original equation and $x=-8$ does not. If they are both negative, why so? Second, it seems it isn't possible to derive $x=0$ from the calculation, so how would I get this answer? Thanks.

Comment: $x=-8$ cannot be a solution because at the given equation you have RHS is a square root, so LHS $\ge 0$, so $x+2\ge 0$, or $x\ge -2$.

Comment: From step (6) to (7) you may only divide by $x$ if it is not $0$. Thus $x=0$ is one solution, then define $x\ne 0$ to go on for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line (7) should be replaced by (7') $x^2(x^2+9x+8)=0$ as @m-stgt pointed it. And you get the possible solution $0$.

Then your reasoning is by *implications*. You've proved that if $x\in \mathbb R$ is a solution, then $x$ can only be equal to $-8$,$-1$ or $0$.

Let's call $S$ the set of solutions :

$$S:=\{x\in \mathbb R|x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}\}$$

You proved that $\boxed{S\subset\{-8,-1,0\}}$. Nothing in what you've done proves that $\{-8,-1,0\}\subset S.$

It remains to be seen whether each of the three possible solutions is suitable.

---

Note : It's the same for $S:=\{x\in \mathbb R: x^2+1=0\}\subset\{-\mathrm i,\mathrm i\}$ and yet $S=\emptyset.$

Answer (score 1):

You are partially correct,

we need $$x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}\ge0\implies x\ge-2$$

Now you have reached at $x^2(x+1)(x+8)=0$

Clearly $x=0,-1$ satisfy $x\ge-2$

Put $x=-8$ in the given equation to reach at $-6=?$ which is obviously false .

Comment: I have a question that may be silly. If $x<-2$, considering $x_0$ as a solution has no sense. Ok. But if $x_1\geq -2$, what guarantees that we will have a solution every time?

Comment: For $x=-8$ your rhs is wrong, $\sqrt{-28}$ instead of $6$.

Comment: @m-stgt, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 0):

$$ x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}$$
$$ (x+2)^2=\left(\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}\right)^2$$
$$ x^2 + 4x + 4=4+x\sqrt{8-x}$$
$$ x^2 + 4x =x\sqrt{8-x}$$
$$ x^2 + 4x - x\sqrt{8-x}= 0$$
$$ x \left( x + 4 - \sqrt{8-x}\right)= 0$$
So one solution is $x=0$
$$  x + 4 - \sqrt{8-x}= 0$$
$$  x + 4 = \sqrt{8-x}$$
$$  (x + 4)^2 = \left(\sqrt{8-x}\right)^2$$
$$  x^2 + 8x + 16 = 8-x$$
$$  x^2 + 9x + 8 = 0$$
$$  (x+1)(x+8) = 0$$
$x=-1$ is another solution

However, we reject $x=-8$ as a solution as substituting back into our original equation we get
$$x+2=\sqrt{4+x\sqrt{8-x}}$$
$$-8+2=\sqrt{4-8\sqrt{8-(-8)}}$$
$$-6=\sqrt{4-8\sqrt{8+8}}$$
$$-6=\sqrt{4-8\sqrt{16}}$$
$$-6=\sqrt{4-8(4)}$$
$$-6=\sqrt{4-32}$$
$$-6=\sqrt{-28}$$

Which is obviously not true. Furthermore, the square root function is not defined for $ x\in \mathbb{R}^- $

Hence our only solutions are $x=0, -1$